# German national, studying in Switzerland, J1 visa for the US, which embassy/consulate?

Tags: j-visa, usa

I am applying for a J1 visa for the US. 
I am studying in Switzerland but I am not a permanent resident there. I am German.

To apply for the visa, to which embassy/consulate do I need to go?

Since I am German and my German home address is my permanent one I would assume that I would have to go to a German consulate.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on the [US Travel Docs website](http://ustraveldocs.com/ch/ch-gen-faq.asp):

> "Applicants are generally advised to apply in their country of nationality or residence. Any person who is legally present in Switzerland may apply for a visa in Switzerland"

As such, you can apply either in Switzerland or Germany.